# Algorithm for Baccalaureate exam on JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I would like to write an algo depending on the mark you have.
If your mark is stictly inferior to 10, you are "recalé".
If it is between 10 and 12 (not included), you are "reçu".
If it is between 12 and 20 (included) you are "reçu avec mention".

```js
let moyenne = 11;

// Ajoutez votre code ici
if (moyenne < 10) {
  console.log("Vous êtes recalé!");
} else if (10 <= moyenne < 12) {
  console.log("Vous êtes reçu!");
} else(12 <= moyenne <= 20) {
  console.log("Vous êtes reçu avec mention!");
}
```

Here is my code : https://repl.it/@LunaShivaya/Bac

As I could see, there is a problem on the last condition.
The two others work, but I don't understand what is the problem.

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: you are using mathematical notation, which doesn't work the same way in javascript. Instead use && between conditions. also, else() is incorrect syntax

Comment: Please add the code to the question to create a [mcve] from next time. If the external link is deleted in the future, the question will be useless. You might also want to tread: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 4):

else(condition) {
is incorrect syntax
and the usage of ( a < b < c) is confusing, with redundant checks, since the initial if statements already check if <.

```js
let moyenne = 11;

// Ajoutez votre code ici
if (moyenne < 10) {
  console.log("Vous êtes recalé!");
} else if (moyenne < 12) {
  console.log("Vous êtes reçu!");
} else if(moyenne <= 20) {
  console.log("Vous êtes reçu avec mention!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer.

I've changed as you suggested, as I could remember I've made some repetitions.
The problem is that the error message is still the same, about an "unexpected token" at line 10.

But I replaced the "else" by an "else if" and the console logs me the correct message. ^^

Anyway, as I could see, I thought we have to finish the algorithm by an "else" and not an "else if".

So I resolved my problem, but still not understanding why the console is reacting this way. ^^

If anyone has an idea (still searching).

Comment: `else {`will match all other conditions which were not matched by your `if(condition) { }` and `else if(condition) { }` blocks.